# How create a column in dataframe1 based on a column created in dataframe2, which is derived by using groupby() on dataframe1

Tags: python, pandas

Firstly I apologise for how poorly worded the title is.

I have 2 pandas dataframes. X_train and crunched_X_train. 
crunched_X_train is derived from X_train by using groupby() on a column named id. 
I then did some stuff on crunched_X_train such that I created a new column in this dataframe named label. For each id in crunched_X_train there was a label in that row. label is a number between 0 and 3.
I want to add this label column to the original X_train such that for every id in X_train there will be a label on that row which is got from crunched_X_train.

I'll try to explain better with the tables. 
I have omitted columns from the tables which don't matter here. 
crunched_X_train:

```
id  label
                        
1   2
2   0
3   1
4   3
5   2
```

I want X_train to look like, with new column label:

```
id  label
1   2
1   2    
1   2
.
.
2   0
2   0
3   1
3   1
```

I hoped I could do it like this but it throws 
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

```
X_train["label"] = crunched_X_train["label"].loc[crunched_X_train["id"] == X_train["id"]]
```

I then tried this iterative approach, which appears to be working. But is bad practise and takes forever.

```
for index, row in X_train.iterrows():
    row["label"] = crunched_X_train["label"].loc[crunched_X_train["id"] == row["id"]]
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the groupby, the id column is the index of `crunched_X_train`. Then you can just that index to join to the original dataframe (where `id` is a column):

```
X_train.join(crunched_X_train["label"], on="id")
```

assuming that `crunched_X_train` has `id` as the index and that `X_train` has the a column named `id`.

See the pandas docs here:
[pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou person who told me join() exists.

```
X_train.join(crunched_X_train["label"], on="id", lsuffix = "label")
```